# How can I build a C++11 vertex attribute class?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es2, c++

How would you build a flexible and efficient vertex attribute class in C++11? What I have:

Vertex attribute roles for using them in shaders:

```
enum AttributeRole
{
    VERTEX0,
    TEXCOORD0, ...
    UNKNOWN_ROLE
};

static const char * AttributeRoleName[UNKNOWN_ROLE + 1] = {
    "vertex0",
    "texcoord0", ...
    "unknown role"
};
```

A class providing vertex attribute type information:

```
struct AttributeTypeInfo {
    GLint m_nrOfComponents;
    GLenum m_glType;
    GLsizei m_bytesPerComponent;
    GLsizei m_bytesPerAttribute;
    GLboolean m_normalize;
    AttributeRole m_role;

    AttributeTypeInfo(GLint nrOfComponents, GLenum glType, GLsizei bytesPerComponent, GLsizei bytesPerAttribute, GLboolean normalize, AttributeRole role)
    : m_nrOfComponents(nrOfComponents), m_glType(glType), m_bytesPerComponent(bytesPerComponent), m_bytesPerAttribute(bytesPerAttribute), m_normalize(normalize), m_role(role)
    {
    }
};
```

A class holding a single vertex attribute:

```
template <typename COMPONENTTYPE, GLenum GLTYPE, size_t NROFCOMPONENTS, GLboolean NORMALIZE, AttributeRole ROLE>
struct Attribute
{
    COMPONENTTYPE m_data[NROFCOMPONENTS]; //attribute data
    static const AttributeTypeInfo m_typeInfo = AttributeTypeInfo(NROFCOMPONENTS, GLTYPE, sizeof(COMPONENTTYPE), sizeof(COMPONENTTYPE) * NROFCOMPONENTS, NORMALIZE, ROLE); //attribute type information
    //... and some access functions...
};

typedef Attribute<GLfloat, GL_FLOAT, 3, GL_FALSE, VERTEX0> Vertex0_V3F;
typedef Attribute<GLubyte, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 4, GL_TRUE, COLOR0> Color0_C4UB;
```

This is quite comfortable, but now I want to combine vertex attributes in an interleaved attribute format to be used in buffers later:

```
/// @brief Dual attribute vertex format
template <typename TYPE0, typename TYPE1>
struct AttributeFormat2
{
    TYPE0 m_attribute0;
    TYPE1 m_attribute1;
    static const size_t m_nrOfAttributes = 2;
    static const size_t m_sizeOfAttributes = sizeof(TYPE0) + sizeof(TYPE1);
    static const AttributeTypeInfo m_typeInfo[m_nrOfAttributes];
};

template <typename TYPE0, typename TYPE1>
const AttributeTypeInfo AttributeFormat2<TYPE0, TYPE1>::m_typeInfo[] = {
    TYPE0::m_typeInfo, 
    TYPE1::m_typeInfo
};

typedef AttributeFormat2<Vertex0_V3F, Color0_C4UB> Format_V3F_C4UB;
```

This gets a bit out of hand when you have 3,4,5 or more vertex attributes...

Is there a (variadic) template solution to the problem with C++11 or 14 or can you suggest a better interleaved vertex attribute format class?

Comment: I am working on something similar for quite a time and I v come to conclusion that using templates is conceptually wrong. They are resolved at compile time and thus you would have to compile all your shaders somewhere into the executable - that would kill the purpose, at least for me.

Comment: No. You don't compile your shaders into the executable and do not resolve at compile time. The names in "AttributeRoleName" are only there to automatically resolve the attribute in the buffer to the attribute in the shader when drawing. Templates are imo a good match for vertex attributes, because they are indeed fix at compile time.

Comment: My solution to this problem does not involve templates. Are you *specifically* interested in one that uses templates? If so, why? It looks like your solution combines both describing the arrangement of the attributes and providing storage for them as well (COMPONENTTYPE m_data[NROFCOMPONENTS];). Is that a requirement as well? If so, why? Knowing those details will probably help you get a better answer.

Comment: I find it convenient to be able to write stuff like "vertexData.attribute0 = ..." or "vertexData.attribute0.setX(0.3f);", so I would like to keep the (Single-)"Attribute" template class. The arrangement of multiple attributes into an interleaved attribute ("Format") is what I'm looking for, so if you have a different solution for this, I'd love to hear it... I chose templates to have most of the stuff checked at compile time, which I find practical.

Comment: This is how I implemented it myself: I've rolled my own templated vec2/3/4 classes and my own tuple-like class for them. Arrays of these tuples can be uploaded as vertex data and there is a separate template function to set up attributes based on a specific tuple layout. Unfortunately there is no attribute naming nor additinal configuration, but it's enough for my needs.https://bitbucket.org/HolyBlackCat/grid-space-fleets/src/05daff3e5013241f31567727287388907c9a9e9a/src/graphics.h?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Wow! Now this is some template black magic you have there. Your "TypePack" template is almost the thing I am looking for... I have cut-pasted the necessary code to try it out to coliru [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8290782990858be1). Note that it needs C++14.